# What settings affect user name in Git?

Tags: git, git-config

I wanted to change the user name in my git configurations, but when I think I change the user name or email (in `.gitconfig` file) it restores back to the previous one. I have also tried doing it through `git config --global user.name <user-name>` but it "restores" back as well.

Where else should I look?  What are the (other) ways to tune my user name in Git?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually changing it?

Comment: Provide what commands are you trying (or what are you doing in GUI).

Comment: I tried to improve the question to make it look less like "help me please".

Comment: 1. Does it display some messages?; 2. Windows? (Cygwin or msysgit?); 3. How do you check that "git config" worked? 4. How do you see that it "restored" back (and after which command)?

Comment: There are 2 config files: global and per-repository. "git config --global" is for global configuration, just "git config" is for per-repository. And where ".gitconfig" file you are speaking about is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git config user.name <user-name`> 
takes precedence i believe, you can find the information in your repository `$REPO_DIR/.git/config`