# Gitbash - How to change default user@hostname

Tags: git, github

I have installed the github for windows and I am unable to change the user@hostname in the git bash. I am new to git please let me know how to change the user and the hostname. I am trying to connect via gitbash to a private git hosting server.

Comment: I am not familiar with github's tools, but did you look at related git questions like e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781863/what-settings-affect-user-name-in-git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and first change your username and email in the GitHub for Windows option  (click on the Tools icon)

[image: username]

The [OP Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924943/dinesh) does insist that the default username and host is displaying the profile and the system name.
He asks if it is possible to change the default one to his custom username and host, because the user and the host will not be changed.

I reply:

I believe the gitbash display your local hostname no matter what the remote repo you are cloning.
**You will be able to register a custom username within the cloned repo with a `git config user.name xxx`**: even if the gitbash still displays your local username and hostname, that won't prevent the commits to use the correct username of the local git config, and to use the credentials you want when pushing back to the upstream repo.

The OP [concludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188265/gitbash-how-to-change-default-userhostname/17188813?noredirect=1#comment24920888_17188813):

> So, I can set the individual `.gitconfig` for each repo so when committing it will use that config. Since I know my host and user wont be changed I think I will set the credentials global config.

Comment: I tried editing the configuration but it does not seem to affect the gitbash default user@host names. Is there any other thing I am missing or any other configurations overriding the default ones?.

Comment: @Dinesh is your gitbash opened in a local repo?

Comment: I am using gitbash in my local system. The git bash when opened is pointing to default repo folder, so I checked in default repository folder which I set as D:/Git Repositories there was a .gitconfig file located. I moved the file to outside the folder, still it is showing the default user@host.

The default username and host is displaying the profile and the system name.

Comment: @Dinesh then I don't think it would prevent you to `git clone` from that gitbash: you can still `git clone https://username@yourgitserver/yourrepo`, using any username/password you want.

Comment: Is it possible to change the default one to my custom username and host, because the user and the host will not be changed.

Comment: @Dinesh I believe the gitbash display your local hostname no matter what the remote repo you are cloning. You will be able to register a custom username within the cloned repo with a `git config user.name xxx`: even if the gitbash *still* displays your local username and hostname, that won't prevent the commits to use the correct username of the local git config, and to use the credentials you want when pushing back to the upstream repo.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So, I can set the individual .gitconfig for each repo so when committing it will use that config. Since I my host and user wont be changed I think I will set the credentials global config. Thanks for the answer, I am marking the question to resolved.